# How can I create a square list of integers in python?

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to create a square matrix, given an integer input.

For example:

```
# for n=3
m = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9]]
```

my attempt:

```
m = list(list(range(1*i,(n+1)*i,i)) for i in range(1,n+1))
print(m)
```

prints this result:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6], [3, 6, 9]]
```

The array must be square and consist of sequential integers.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Obviously the question is *How to get the correct output*.

Comment: Does it have to have those ascending numbers?

Comment: @Aran-Fey yes ascending.

Comment: @Agile_Eagle The output the OP has is a square matrix. But you are right, they probably want formatted string output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
n = 3
m = [list(range(1+n*i, 1+n*(i+1))) for i in range(n)]

[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

The main misunderstanding appears to be in *spotting the pattern*. For example, the first value in each column can be computed via `1 + 3 * i`, where `i` iterates over `0, 1, 2`. For the `end` argument of `range`, you just need to add *n* to the formula, and we can use the identity:

```
n*i + n = n*(i+1)
```

As an aside, if you are happy to use a 3rd party library, this is trivial with NumPy:

```
import numpy as np

n = 3
A = np.arange(1, n**2 + 1).reshape((n, n))

array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

Comment: Now i see, thank you very much for your detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

i rather use numpy (**IT IS NOT A LIST** so i know it's not the required OP, however it can still be interesting)

```
def func(n):
    l = np.asarray([i for i in range(1,n**2+1)])
    return l.reshape(n,n)

func(3)
>>> array([[1, 2, 3],
          [4, 5, 6],
          [7, 8, 9]])
```

take also in consideration the time to compute:

```
def func(n):
   t = time.time()
   np.arange(1, n**2 + 1).reshape((n, n))
   t1 = time.time()-t
   t = time.time()
   np.asarray([i for i in range(1,n**2+1)]).reshape(n,n)
   t2 = time.time()-t
   t = time.time()
   [list(range(1+n*i, 1+n*(i+1))) for i in range(n)]
   t3 = time.time()-t
   t = time.time()
   itr = itertools.count(1)  # start counting at 1
   matrix = [[next(itr) for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]
   t4 = time.time()-t
   return [t1,t2,t3,t4]

plt.plot([re[0] for re in res],'r',label = 'numpy')
plt.plot([re[1] for re in res],'b',label = 'asarray')
plt.plot([re[2] for re in res],'m',label = 'list')
plt.plot([re[3] for re in res],'g',label = 'itertool')
plt.legend()
plt.savefig('plt1.png')
```

will give the following graph for 200 points:
[image]

for large matrix, go straight for the numpy solution of @jpp

Comment: Since you already invested your time in creating a plot, why not make it perfect by adding the legends so that it's easy to see/follow which color belongs to which method.

Comment: Can you share the code for the plotting procedure, please?

Comment: @GVelascoh Updated

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) to create an iterator that yields ascending numbers, and then advance that iterator in a nested [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) using the [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) function:

```
import itertools

n = 3

itr = itertools.count(1)  # start counting at 1
matrix = [[next(itr) for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]
# result: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: using `itr = iter(range(1,n*n+1))` as the iterator will work as well, without itertools.

Answer (score 0):

You can use comprehensive lists. For a zero-filled matrix:

```
mat = [[0 for i in range(N)] for i in range(N)]
```

For a matrix with consecutive elements (zero-based):

```
mat = [[(N*j + i) for i in range(N)] for j in range(N)]
```

For a matrix with consecutive elements (one-based):

```
mat = [[(N*j + i +1) for i in range(N)] for j in range(N)]
```

And for a square print you can use:

```
>>> print(*mat,sep="\n")
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: I was creating an empty matrix as it was not specified in the question what the elements should be.